# How to add an abstract class in the middle with a call to a function using java?

Tags: java, abstract-class, java-7

I have the following structure:

```
public abstract class BaseCall<T> implements Callable<T> {

    public abstract T innerCall();

    protected Structure getProxy() {
       return SomeStructure;
    }
}
```

And at least 4 classes that look like that:

```
public class GetXCall extends BaseCall<Set<String>> {

    private final Credentials credentials;

    public GetXCall (Credentials credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> innerCall() {
        return getProxy().getXfromVC(credentials);
    }

}

public class GetYCall extends BaseCall<Set<String>> {

    private final Credentials credentials;

    public GetYCall (Credentials credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> innerCall() {
        return getProxy().getYfromVC(credentials);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it prettier and add another abstract class in the middle so I can just pass the function `getYfromVC` or `getXfromVC`and the abstract class will call something like :

```
getProxy()._____(credentials)
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work as I can't use `run` inside

```
public abstract class RunVcTask<T> extends BaseCall<T> {

    private final Credentials credentials;

    public RunVcTask(Credentials credentials)    {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public abstract T run();

    @Override
    public T innerCall() {
        return getProxy().run(credentials); //HERE the run can't work
    }
}
```

As `InnerCall` not always uses credentials, I can't change it to `abstract innerCall(Credentials c)`

can someone advise if there is a nice way to do it?
(I'm currently using java 7)

Comment: you will just have to call it getfromVC()

Comment: what? can you please explain. the getProxy() can't call 'run'

Comment: Your classes are already very simple, it is not clear why you need to simplify it more

Comment: I have more than 4 classes that are getXCall, each has the same constructor, and always calls getProxy - just wanted to make it easier to add mote 'getSomeCalls' in the future

Comment: google strategy and visitor patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick to inheritance, there is no simplification possible beyond

```
public abstract class BaseCall<T> implements Callable<T> {

    public abstract T innerCall();

    protected Structure getProxy() {
       return SomeStructure;
    }
}
public abstract class RunVcTask<T> extends BaseCall<T> {

    private final Credentials credentials;

    public RunVcTask(Credentials credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public abstract T actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials);

    @Override
    public T innerCall() {
        return actualOp(getProxy(), credentials);
    }
}

public class GetXCall extends RunVcTask<Set<String>> {
    public GetXCall(Credentials credentials) {
        super(credentials);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials) {
        return proxy.getXfromVC(credentials);
    }
}
public class GetYCall extends RunVcTask<Set<String>> {
    public GetYCall(Credentials credentials) {
        super(credentials);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials) {
        return proxy.getXfromVC(credentials);
    }
}
```

A better approach is using *delegation*:

```
public class RunVcTask<T> extends BaseCall<T> {
    interface ActualTask<T> {
        T actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials);
    }
    enum BuiltIn implements ActualTask<Set<String>> {
        GetX {
            public Set<String> actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials) {
                return proxy.getXfromVC(credentials);
            }
        },
        GetY {
            public Set<String> actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials) {
                return proxy.getYfromVC(credentials);
            }
        },
    }

    private final Credentials credentials;
    private final ActualTask<T> delegate;

    public RunVcTask(Credentials credentials, ActualTask<T> task) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.delegate = task;
    }

    @Override
    public T innerCall() {
        return delegate.actualOp(getProxy(), credentials);
    }
}
```

Here, no special subclass for `GetX`, `GetY`, etc is needed, you can instantiate such a call via

```
BaseCall<Set<String>> getXInstance = new RunVcTask<>(credentials, RunVcTask.BuiltIn.GetX);
BaseCall<Set<String>> getYInstance = new RunVcTask<>(credentials, RunVcTask.BuiltIn.GetY);
```

so the specialization code of a particular function reduces to the four lines within the `BuiltIn` `enum`. Only actions with the same return type can be aggregated within such an `enum`, so you would have to use multiple `enum`s for different types (they don’t need to be nested within `RunVcTask`) or use anonymous inner classes instead, which is only slightly bigger:

```
BaseCall<Set<String>> getXInstance = new RunVcTask<>(credentials,
    new RunVcTask.ActualTask<Set<String>>() {
        public Set<String> actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials) {
            return proxy.getXfromVC(credentials);
        }
    });
BaseCall<Set<String>> getYInstance = new RunVcTask<>(credentials,
    new RunVcTask.ActualTask<Set<String>>() {
        public Set<String> actualOp(Structure proxy, Credentials credentials) {
            return proxy.getYfromVC(credentials);
        }
    });
```

You could also use anonymous inner classes of `RunVcTask` in the inheritance example, shortening the code to a similar degree, but the delegation approach also provides you with a road map to Java 8, once you are able to switch:

```
BaseCall<Set<String>> getXInstance = new RunVcTask<>(credentials, Structure::getXfromVC);
BaseCall<Set<String>> getYInstance = new RunVcTask<>(credentials, Structure::getYfromVC);
```